# issue with EOF command inside a shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, stored-procedures

I have a code snippet which looks like below.

```
if [ $output -le 0 ]
then
    echo 'no data present'
    echo "$ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD"
    $ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD <<EOF
    set serverout on 
    set linesize 1000
    set feedback off
    BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('inserting into mig_log');
    INSERT INTO ROAMING_LOG VALUES(SYSDATE,'NEW RECORD CREATION IN BSCS',0,0,0,0,0,'No new Roaming Partner created.','N');
    COMMIT;
    END;
    /
    EOF
    echo 'data inserted'
    echo 'mail to sent'
    echo -e "$BODY4"| mailx -s "$SUBJECT" ${TO_ADDRESS} -- -r ${FROM_ADDRESS}
    echo 'mail sent'
fi
```

this snippet throws an error

> "SP2-0042: unknown command "EOF" - rest of line ignored."

Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is called a "[here document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument)", and requires the *whole line* ending the document to be equal to the delimiter that you use to start the text block. So for this to work in any shell you'd have to either de-dent the `EOF` line or change the delimiter to `'    EOF'`.

Answer (score 1):

The end token `EOF` should not be indented. So you need to change the code to

```
    $ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD <<EOF
    #some stuff here
EOF
```

If you wish to indent the end token of the heredoc, and if you're using `GNU-Bash`, you can use `<<-`

```
$ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD <<-EOF
    #some stuff here
    EOF
```

Comment: @GourabSengupta : You're welcome, I am not sure in which version of the `bash` was the `<<-` added. Do check the out. :)

Comment: I just changed the indentation n it worked... but will surely check that out...just posted another question...hope u will be able to help @sjsam :)

Answer (score 0):

simple way use script like this

```
L=$(ORACLEHOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD <<EOF
    #some stuff here
EOF)
```